# create custom arabic keyboard for android

Tags: android, mobile, keyboard, keycode

i wanna crate custom keyboard in android.
i wanna use this code
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615[^]

but now i wanna make Arabic keyboard but i have problem with that because Arabic ASCII code is two part and the XML doesn't support that
i use this site to convert: http://www.asciitohex.com/[^]

for example 'ش' code is '216 180' but i can't use that in this XML:

Answer (score 1):

for arabic,persian ,etc (utf-8) character custom keyboards you should use you characeter in java class instead ,
the algorithm is find the keycode that is defined in xml and use they equal character in arabic with that,

as the tutorial above they code for "ش" character should look something like this:

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch (primaryCode) {
    case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
        ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        break;
    case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
        caps = !caps;
        keyboard.setShifted(caps);
        kv.invalidateAllKeys();
        break;
    case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        break;
    default:
        char code = (char) primaryCode;
        if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
            code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
        }
        if (code == 97) {
            ic.commitText(" ش",1);// your character

        } else {
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
        }
    }
}
```